# How to request param checkout magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout

I want to send another email after pressing place order.
But could not get the value entered by request param in observer. Here is my code

Mymodule\CheckoutCustom\etc\events.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_before">
        <observer name="Mymodule_checkout_affter" instance="Mymodule\CheckoutCustom\Observer\EmailCc" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Mymodule\CheckoutCustom\Observer\EmailCc.php

```
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
class EmailCc implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    protected $request;

    public function __construct(
        RequestInterface $request
    )
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {

        $emailCCfrontend = $this->request->getParam('checkout_email_cc');

        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/templog.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info($emailCCfrontend);
    }
}
```

checkout_index_index.xml

```
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="before-form" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="checkout_email_cc" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm</item>
                                                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                                        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/email</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm.checkout_email_cc</item>
                                                                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Email CC</item>
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http;

class EmailCc implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
private $request;
public function __construct(
        Http $request
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;

    }

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{

    $emailCCfrontend = $this->request->getParam('checkout_email_cc');
    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/templog.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    $logger->info($emailCCfrontend);
}


}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't get the value of checkout_email_cc. Do you have any more answers.